# CSS/HTML grid has mystery gap

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I have a grid of article items which was working in the past but now there are some "gaps" in the layout.  All items in the grid are using the same CSS, so I can't see why the gaps are there.  I've put it in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/schatzkin/0fh30d7h/1/  The original page is in WordPress but I don't see that as the source of the problem.

Here's the relevant bit of CSS:

```
.featured-grid {
  float: left;
  min-height: 425px;
  margin: 1em .5em 0 0;
  width: 31%; }

.featured-title-grid h4 {
  font-size: 18px; }

 .featured-author-grid {
  float: left; }

.featured-date-grid {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 15px; }


.featured-image-grid {
 clear: left;
 height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  padding: 1em 0 1em; }

.featured-date-feed {
  clear: left;
  margin: 1em 0 0; }

.featured-news-feed {
  background: #efefef;
  float: left;
  margin: .5em 2em 2em 0;
 padding: .5em; }
```

Comment: Can you clarify which gaps you're seeing? I don't see anything unsightly in the JSFiddle demo on Firefox.

Comment: I'm seeing (also in Firefox) that in the second row there is nothing in the first column, and in the third row there is nothing in the first or second column.

Comment: There just way too much code to go through to isolate the issue. If you could provide the minimal markup to go along with the CSS you posted in the question, your problem might get solved a lot faster. Also, using *just* the CSS you provided doesn't reproduce the error, so you need to add a little more CSS, please.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've slimmed down both the css and html in jsfiddle.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0fh30d7h/5/); you're updated fiddle still has over a thousand lines of CSS and hundreds of lines of HTML that aren't related to the problem at all.

Comment: I've narrowed the example down to the minimal code necessary to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/0fh30d7h/9/ Check it out and replace your HTML and CSS in the post above with that of the fiddle in this comment. (13 lines of CSS down from over 2600...)

Comment: Basically the issue seems to be you have a min-height but no height declared for `.featured-grid`. http://jsfiddle.net/0fh30d7h/10/ Set a fixed height for your `h4` item titles and for your `.featured-grid` item containers and they should be easier to line up.

Comment: TylerH, you are such a pal.  Many, many thanks for your patience and work.  I'm obviously new to putting code examples in jsfiddle for others to see so I've learned a lot in this round.  Problem fixed!